# how to download all files with matching key from S3, using aws-sdk module in Node?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

say in S3 bucket `s3://my-bucket-name`

I had the following files:

`file1.txt`

`file2.txt`

`file3.txt`

`abc.txt`

`one.txt`

If I wanted to download files matching regex `file*.txt`,
is it achievable through `aws-sdk` node module? If not what is something I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://gist.github.com/newtriks/8849948
 and add a condition after line 22 with regexep https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

```
var str = filename 
var result = str.match('^file.*.txt');
if(!result)
    result='no match'
```

Comment: Write better your responses.